# Connecting Marketing Cloud to Sales Cloud via Connector and "Connect Accounts" option under "Salesforce Integration" - Insufficient Privileges

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

I'm a Marketing Cloud Developer assisting in finishing up a Marketing Cloud Connect integration.  All steps have been completed, at least 97% of them.  We are having one (hopefully) last issue.  And that is, signing into Sales Cloud as the Marketing Cloud System User, then going to Marketing Cloud > Email Studio > Admin > Salesforce Integration > Connect Accounts.  When we click "Connect Account" the Sales Cloud browser window says "Insufficient Permissions".

Here we are at the place to "Connect Account":
[image]

Then, when we click "Connect Account":
[image]

Something I feel is worth mentioning is that the client is using SSO to sign into Sales Cloud.  The client signs into Sales Cloud using a login user name that's different than the Marketing Cloud System User in Sales Cloud.  After they sign in, they go to Users, clicks on the Marketing Cloud System User, and clicks "Login".  Now, we are at the Sales Cloud home screen logged in as the Marketing Cloud System User.

I've verified that the Marketing Cloud System User has "Marketing User" checkbox checked and Marketing Cloud System Admin permission set.  What could I be missing?

Comment: I am not sure, but there could be a setting on the user to turn off SSO. We did kind of a similar thing, when connecting Sales Cloud with a different marketing automation platform.

Comment: Is the Sales Cloud user also an Admin?